# set github workflow environment variable based on branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow that I want to change based on the branch thats running.
Example below I want to update the **TAG_PREXIX** based on the branch name.
If branch is called release/test I want `TAG_PREXIX = release-v` if its main then it should be `TAG_PREXIX=main-v`

```
name: Release
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - release/*
env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}-image
  TAG_PREXIX: ${{github.branch-v}}

jobs:
  Release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

Comment: The behavior isn't the same for the `main` and the `release/*`syntax. For example this syntax would work for the main branch, at the env level, but not for the `release/*` branches `TAG_PREXIX: ${GITHUB_REF##*/}-v`. Would it be an option to use different env variables depending on the branch name structure?

Comment: So your saying even if you could set variable based on env they would not work because main in run in one environment and release is in another so they would not see the variable set ? Hmm using branch name might be an option. I'll look into that.

Comment: It's not exactly that. The problem is that the expression to extract the branch name to generate the `main-v` or the `release-v` isn't the same, as in one case you want the prefix, and in the other one the suffix. Using two different env variable would help in that case.